# Java Message sent from client to server

Tags: java

I'm using a socket to connect my client with the server, I need a way so that when somebody tries to login on the client with an account, it sends the username and password to the server, and checks if the account exists. I just need to know how to make it send the message to the server when they press login.

i tried this to make it send a message to the server

```
public static void sendmsg(String a, String b)
    {
        try
        {
            String host = "127.0.0.1";
            int port = 43655;
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            socket = new Socket(address, port);

            //Send the message to the server
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);


            String sendMessage = a;
            bw.write(sendMessage);
            bw.flush();
            System.out.println("Message sent to the server : "+sendMessage);

            //Get the return message from the server
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String message = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from the server : " +message);
        }
        catch (Exception exception) 
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            //Closing the socket
            try
            {
                socket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: We need more information. Have you already tried something ? If so, where are you stuck ?

Comment: Well i tried making a method where i could send a message to the server like this - public void msgServer(String a, String b) { but i couldn't figure out how to make it send the message to the server.

Comment: Are you maintaining a connection to the server elsewhere in the code? This code will attempt to establish a NEW connection each time the method sendnsg is called, which may not be the desired behavior.

Comment: Have you written the server program as well? Add the output of the client as well as server programs.

Comment: yes there is already a connection sending a message when the server starts up and a client joins, it's from public void main(string args[]) {

Answer (score 1):

nice you are working with Sockets, well I have an approach you can try, and maybe if it is useful you can consider for your implementation.

First of all I will create an entity to handle those values and fill it with the incoming data.

```
class UserAuth {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    //Consider here your getters and setters, I am not including them       
}
```

I will use the entity as the parameter for the method while sending and maybe you can fill it as something like:

```
UserAuth attemptingUser = new UserAuth(...)
```

ObjectInputStream works fine for these kind of scenarios. If you still want to work with Strings, you can use BufferedReader and try to merge your username and password as one single String and use the .readLine() method to obtain (separated with commas), then use String methods such Split but I find that could take some more time, should be better if you handle it with an object. But it depends on the complexity you want to add to your application :).

```
class AuthClient {

    public void sendMsg(UserAuth attemptingUser) {
        String host =  "localhost";
        int port = 2055;
        //1. Create the socket
        Socket sender = new Socket(host, port);
        //2. Create an object output stream to write the object into the stream
        ObjectOutputStream outputWriter = new ObjectOutputStream(sender.getOutputStream());
        //3. Write (send the object)
        outputWriter.writeObject(attemptingUser);
        //4. Close
        outputWriter.close();
        sender.close();
    }
}

class AuthServer {

    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2055);

    public void receiveMsg() {
        //1. Accept the connection
        Socket conn = ss.accept();
        //2. Receive the flow
        ObjectInputStream readStream = new ObjectInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        //3. Read the object
        UserAuth userReceived = readStream.readObject();
        //4. Verify against file, db or whatever
        if (userReceived.getUsername().equals("admin") && userReceived.getPassword().equals("admin")) {
            //Authentication
        }
    }

}
```

(This is added as the part I edit for what you asked me in the comments)

```
public void sendMsg(String username, String password) {
            String host =  "localhost";
            int port = 2055;
            //1. Create the socket
            Socket sender = new Socket(host, port);
            //2. Create the UserAuth object based on the parameters you received
            UserAuth myuser = new UserAuth();
            myuser.setUsername(username);
            myuser.setPassword(password);
            //3. Follow same instructions for the creation of ObjectOutputStream...
            ObjectOutputStream objectWriter = new ObjectOutputStream(sender.getOutputStream());
            objectWriter.writeObject(myuser);
            //That is what I would use if I keep your structure
        }
```

If you want to keep your structure using Strings, I would simplify and reduce impact of I/O by using the String methods. Since you know you are always expecting user/password, I would merge your two params in one single String or use special char and on server side handle with `StringTokenizer` class. Or maybe handle with the "split" method. You have many options here.

So far, this will be my approach for the problem you are facing. Hope it helps somehow. Best regards and happy coding :).

Comment: Is there a way to do this without opening another socket? the server already has one, so I don't want it to close that one I want it to use the same one

Comment: what you mean by opening another socket? In order to send your message in this kind of scenarios, you need two sockets. The server one which is the one which handles the server connections and the other socket is the incoming connection which is the accepted client. Or what is exactly what you want to do?

Comment: oh ok, how come I get errors when I add these though? its something to do with UserAuth attemptingUser = new UserAuth(...)                         I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: I made an edit on the answer to make it more clear. Sorry for the delay on the answer, I was sick last night, could not connect to so.

Comment: so confused right now... how am I supposed to implement this? when I try I get errors

Comment: could you tell me what is the error or exception you are getting?

Comment: ok, what IDE are you using? These are not errors about logic or something like that. Those seem to be missing imports. Did you make sure you are importing the packages required to work with Streams? I suggest you to check if you are using import java.io.*; and also the packages where you define those classes. I mean you should have an implementation of your code like this: UserAuth.java, AuthClient.java, AuthServer.java, (total od 3 files) you can include them in different packages or in the same and make sure you are importing these appropriately.

Comment: i don't use IDEs' they are confusing. i'm a hardcoder :) but I don't understand why these aren't working. I don't need u to make the user name stuff I just need the code for sending a message and the server will automatically read it like right away with no delay.

Comment: I also hardcoder, whenever a problem occurs on server I have to go to Linux servers and change code through vi. I do not understand how an IDE can be confusing :). Anyway... I just made an approach on how I could handle that using ObjectOutputStream which is simplier. As I mention in my post if you still want to do it using String values, you can read in just one line by merging your username and password in one single string and then use String methods (such split) or handling an array of 2 Strings. If you still want to read line by line you can follow the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done looks OK to me but it all depends on what the server is expecting to receive. What is the terminating character as you have not sent one unless it's already contained within your `String a` variable.

If the server is expecting an end of line character (which you don't currently send) you can use a `PrintWriter` instead of a `BufferedWriter` like this

```
pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
pw.println(a);
```

Your server would then be doing something like this

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String value = br.readLine();
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without opening another socket?

Comment: There is only one socket to open. This replaces your code